# 'org.apache.http.HttpEntity' is deprecated. How to solve this error in android studio?

Tags: java, android, apache-httpclient-4.x

i'm using android studio API22 and i have these errors:

```
'org.apache.http.HttpEntity' is deprecated
'org.apache.http.HttpResponse' is deprecated
'org.apache.http.NameValuePair' is deprecated
'org.apache.http.client.HttpClient' is deprecated
'org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity' is deprecated
'org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost' is deprecated
'org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient' is deprecated
'org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair' is deprecated
'org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams' is deprecated
'org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams' is deprecated
'org.apache.http.params.HttpParams' is deprecated
'org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils' is deprecated
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: It is not an error. It is  warning. You should read the documentation. There must be a hint which class you should use

Comment: inspection 'Deprecated API usage' options: edit inspection profile setting, and Annotate class 'HttpEntity' as @Deprecated: edit intention settings. which options should i go for?? i really have no idea what they mean

Answer (score 20):

Add this to your gradle

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

Example

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.0.1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debugSigned {
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Comment: The msebera version is 1.1mb, quite an overhead for a small app. The legacy version is 297k.
okhttp + compatibility jars total 382kb - and would encourage switching over to a modern API - but the compatibility layer doesn't cover enough classes for me.

Answer (score 7):

Quoting [myself](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/03/10/random-musings-android-5p1-sdk.html):

> If you need to continue using the HttpClient API, consider switching to [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) and their HttpClient compatibility layer, or consider switching to [Apache’s separate Android edition of HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html). Otherwise, switch to HttpURLConnection or OkHttp’s native API.

Or, depending upon what you are using HttpClient for, use a more specific networking library (Retrofit for Web services, Picasso or Universal Image Loader for images, etc.).

Also note that HttpClient is removed from the SDK for the M Developer Preview, indicating that it will be removed in the next edition of Android. While there is [a workaround to continue using HttpClient in M](http://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client), you really need to move to something else.

Comment: is there a simple replacement for those classes in API?

Comment: @lamriassia: I have no idea what you would consider "simple" and what you consider "in API" to be. I have listed several replacements in my answer (OkHttp's HttpClient API, Apache's replacement HttpClient, using OkHttp directly, HttpUrlConnection, Retrofit, Picasso, and Universal Image Loader). You will have to decide for yourself which, if any, of those are "simple" and which, if any, are "in API".

Comment: @CommonsWare what have you used finally. Can you share the code that you have written.

Comment: How come "useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'" doesn't help with using the old APIs ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: I moved off of HttpClient a year or two ago; I have not attempted to use the `.legacy` stuff in the M Developer Preview.

Comment: I know it's better to leave it, but we need to check if the app can work fine with the rest of the stuff .

Answer (score 5):

The version of the Apache HTTP client provided on stock Android was [very very old](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/android-port.html).

> Google Android 1.0 was released with a pre-BETA snapshot of Apache HttpClient. To coincide with the first Android release Apache HttpClient 4.0 APIs had to be frozen prematurely, while many of interfaces and internal structures were still not fully worked out. As Apache HttpClient 4.0 was maturing the project was expecting Google to incorporate the latest code improvements into their code tree. Unfortunately it did not happen.

If you don't want to switch over to a new API you can manually add a newer version of the Apache HttpClient library into your project to replace the old deprecated version in Android SDK < 22.

The easiest way to do this when targeting SDK 23+ is to use Marek Sebera's new [Apache HttpClient package for Android](https://github.com/smarek/httpclient-android/wiki/Project-Introduction) (as [suggested by Apache](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/android-port.html)), which could potentially work as a drop-in replacement. Simply add the following dependency to your build.gradle file (updating the version number if appropriate):

`compile "cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.1"`

and replace `import org.apache.http.*` with `import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.*` everywhere in your project.

Note that many classes from the old library are deprecated (e.g. `HttpParams`, `ThreadSafeClientConnManager`), so rewriting the code is probably going to be a better solution.

---

**Edit:** I found some cases where users were getting timeout exceptions when behind proxy servers after we updated to the newer Http client. Since the code is full of deprecated warnings everywhere, we decided that it wasn't worth the effort trying to fix the issue. I recommend testing very thoroughly before trying to put this into production.

As mentioned in other answers, a much better solution is to bite the bullet and switch over to either the native Android `HttpUrlConnection`, or if that doesn't meet your needs, you can use the library `OkHttp`, which is what `HttpUrlConnection` is [internally based upon anyway](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/29p3zz/til_okhttp_engine_is_backing_httpurlconnection_as/).

Comment: Here we are, December 2015, and after adding `cz.msebera.android.httpclient 4.4.1.1` in my app build.gradle, Android Studio 1.5, sdk 23, tells that `HttpParams, HttpConnectionParams, BasicHttpParams, HttpProtocolParams` and `DefaultHttpClient` are deprecated. It seems I'll have to recode everything from scratch.

Answer (score 4):

HttpClient deperected from android lollypop 5.1 (API 22) :-

But still we can use HttpClient by using following code in Android studio:-

Goto app\build.gradle file:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.XXXXX.XXX"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        -----------
        -----------

        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
```

[OR ALTERNATIVE]

Download and add [HttpClient jar](https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) files to your project or use [okHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/).

Answer (score 1):

Use Following Dependency in your Gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the `org.apache.http.legacy` jar file from [here](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi).

In the `build.gradle` file, type the following code

```
defaultConfig {
      useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Save the downloaded .jar file in the following location

```
./sdk/platforms/android-23/optional/(.jar file)
```

I am using android-23 under platforms, it depends on which API level you are using. If the optional folder does not exist, create the optional folder and paste the .jar file in it before syncing the gradle project.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your gradle

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

Example

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.0.1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debugSigned {
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

This library will allow you to use it without problem, at least I didn't had any problem till now with it.

Comment: This Looks like an exact copy of the answer of @bfacumat