# Android Gradle Apache HttpClient does not exist?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to convert an IntelliJ project to the Gradle system of Android Studio but I am running into errors with Apache HttpClient? Am I missing something, the errors I am getting are as follows:

```
Error:(10, 30) error: package org.apache.http.client does not exist
Error:(11, 30) error: package org.apache.http.client does not exist
Error:(12, 37) error: package org.apache.http.client.entity does not exist
Error:(13, 38) error: package org.apache.http.client.methods does not exist
Error:(14, 38) error: package org.apache.http.client.methods does not exist
Error:(15, 38) error: package org.apache.http.client.methods does not exist
Error:(16, 35) error: package org.apache.http.impl.client does not exist
Error:(134, 33) error: cannot find symbol class HttpUriRequest
Error:(164, 39) error: cannot find symbol class HttpUriRequest
Error:(106, 17) error: cannot find symbol class HttpGet
Error:(106, 39) error: cannot find symbol class HttpGet
Error:(117, 17) error: cannot find symbol class HttpPost
Error:(117, 40) error: cannot find symbol class HttpPost
Error:(125, 43) error: cannot find symbol class UrlEncodedFormEntity
Error:(135, 9) error: cannot find symbol class HttpClient
Error:(135, 33) error: cannot find symbol class DefaultHttpClient
Error:(155, 18) error: cannot find symbol class ClientProtocolException
Error:(165, 9) error: cannot find symbol class HttpClient
Error:(165, 33) error: cannot find symbol class DefaultHttpClient
Error:(185, 18) error: cannot find symbol class ClientProtocolException
```

My build.gradle file has the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.6'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.6'
    compile files('libs/core.jar')
}
```

It seems a lot of people are getting a similar problem but neither SO or Google have a solution so I am hoping this question will help future searchers.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I suggest you replace the deprecated apache HttpClient with the new HttpURLConnection.

That's a cleaner solution, it's quite easy to migrate, and generally it's better to stick to the latest SDK changes than trying to hack/patch/workaround: you usually regret it later :)

**Step 1**

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
```

becomes:

```
URL urlObj = new URL(url);
```

**Step 2**

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

becomes:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

**Step 2 bis**

```
int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

becomes:

```
int status = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
```

Comment: Hey @Benjamin, how to send URL with PUT method?

Comment: @TrickySolutions Sorry no idea, haven't used the PUT method yet.

Comment: This is not a real solution!  Look below for @Jinu's answer.

Answer (score 530):

if you are using target sdk as 23 add below code in your build.gradle

```
android{
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

and change your buildscript to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
```

for more info follow this [link](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)

Comment: Supplied String module notation 'org.apache.http.legacy' is invalid.

Comment: change your buildscript  to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

Comment: Already had 1.3.1. Still cannot resolve classes inside Android Studio: `Error:(14, 23) error: package org.apache.http does not exist`

Comment: is your targetSdkVersion 23 and build tools 23.0.0

Comment: Yes, of course. Do your imports work fine? What Android Studio version are you using?

Comment: android studio 1.4 beta 2

Comment: And what if you want to use the latest version of apache http components?

Comment: @Silviu you can find dependency from here http://gradleplease.appspot.com/#httpmime

Comment: Thanx Jinu, updating Android Studio from 1.3 to above version is must. Got it working

Comment: i used this tutorial http://www.blazin.in/2016/03/http-connection-for-android-marshmallow.html it worked for me using HttpOpenUrlConnection clases

Comment: Working, Thanks. 'org.apache.http.legacy' helped me, gradle was updated previously

Answer (score 97):

I had this problem and then found these pages:
Here you can see that apache library is deprecated, but it's not removed, so it should work. It doesn't.

[See](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/package-summary.html).

And here you can see how to include apache library to your project

[See](http://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client).

I resolved problem by adding following to my build.gradle file as recommended in second link.

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

However this only works if you are using gradle 1.3.0-beta2 or greater, so you will have to add this to buildscript dependencies if you are on a lower version:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0-beta2'
```

Comment: For me it failed with: Error:Execution failed for task ':xenoAmp:mergeDebugJavaResources'.
> Cannot determine expansion folder for L:\Projekty\xenoampgit\xenoAmp\build\intermediates\packagedJarsJavaResources\debug\httpclient-android-4.3.5.1.jar1037172435\META-INF\LICENSE with folders L:\Projekty\xenoampgit\xenoAmp\build\intermediates\sourceFolderJavaResources\debug,L:\Projekty\xenoampgit\xenoAmp\build\intermediates\packagedJarsJavaResources\debug

Comment: @ssuukk Hi, did you find a solution for this error?

Comment: Unfortunately the solution was to change target to current highest API, and that broke A LOT of things! Then I've had to add "useLibrary", "classpath" PLUS reference legacy apache lib, as described elsewhere in this question. And after it was compilable again I just decided to ditch Apache code altogether and replace it all with URLConnection, which was easier than I thought.

Comment: Agree with ssuukk.  None of these answers worked for me so I ended up getting rid of the Apache libraries as well.  I am pretty new to Android development but it was straightforward.

Comment: I had the same issue and I fixed with     useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
how Milos said... however for @ssuukk with your issue you can try adding this always: android {  packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST'
    }}

Answer (score 64):

Add this library into `build.gradle`

```
 android {
      useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
 }
```

Comment: can someone explain this? Why does this make it work? Why do we need to add this line, aside from adding the dependencies?

Comment: @Dan it's because the org.apache.http library was removed with version 23.

Comment: To clarify, this doesn't go into the root `build.gradle`, but rather within the module folder you're building (ie "app")

Answer (score 37):

copy `org.apache.http.legacy.jar` which is in `Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23/optional` folder to to `app/libs`

and also added this line to app.gradle file

```
compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
```

But if you're using more jar libraries, you can use this way

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Comment: In another of my projects this proved to be the only answer that worked so +1 and thanks.

Comment: why isnt this the answer?

Comment: Same for me. Someone should accept this answer instead the one accepted now.

Comment: This is the least path of resistance, not sure I want to down-grade gradle. It compile fine for me.

Comment: Thanks! This works with the gradle-experimental 0.6.0-alpha5 plugin. "useLibrary" doesn't seem to exist in the experimental plugin.

Comment: helped without disturbing the other settings. thanks

Comment: helped in June 2016 :D (y) Eclipse still FTW :p

Comment: Yea buddy! Thanks! great answer

Comment: Great answer! Tried alot of other answers but changing one things broke other. This solution worked for me without change any existing configuration

Answer (score 18):

Basically all you need to do is add:

```
useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

To your `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 10):

I ran into similar problems, you might be able to get it to work using a similar method.

First, try this with your current configuration, exclude `httpclient` from `httpmime`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile ('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.6'){
            exclude module: 'httpclient'
        }
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.6'
}
```

In my case, I fixed it by using the following jars :

- [httpclient-android-4.3.5.1.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-android/4.3.5.1)
- [httpmime-4.3.5.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.3.5)

Then, in the build.gradle, excluding `httpclient` from `httpmime`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.5') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, im afraid neither worked for me though :(

Comment: @tur that's strange, the second option worked for me. Make sure that your old jar files are deleted for the second option.

Comment: What is `libs/core.jar` for?

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same issue. Daniel Nugent's answer helped a bit (after following his advice `HttpResponse` was found - but the `HttpClient` was still missing).

So here is what fixed it for me:

1. (if not already done, commend previous import-statements out)
2. visit http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi
3. get the `4.5.1.zip` from the binary section
4. unzip it and paste `httpcore-4.4.3` & `httpclient-4.5.1.jar` in `project/libs` folder
5. right-click the jar and choose *Add as library*.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 7):

Perfect Answer by Jinu  and Daniel

Adding to this 
I solved the Issue by Using This, if your compileSdkVersion is 19(IN MY CASE)

```
compile ('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
}
compile ('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
}
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2'
```

else if your compileSdkVersion is 23
then use

```
android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is what I did, and it works for me.

step 1: add this in the build.grade(module: app)

```
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
```

step 2: sync the project and done.

Comment: it failed to resolve with error "Failed to resolve: org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.cli‌​‌​ent:4.1.2". I am using experimental gradle 0.6.0-beta. can you figure it out ?

Answer (score 2):

After spending days on the subject, I managed to solve it finally. Unfortunately we need it if we want to use expansion files. The solution has been provided by a few people here, but for me the answers were missing a few minor detail that could have saved a lot of time for me. Here is the sequence of events for novices like me to save your precious time.

First I imported the "library" folder from D:\Users\Imre\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\extras\google\play_licensing to the project by going into File, New, Import Module and navigating to the "library" folder. If you open the SDK Manager and click on "Launch Standalone SDK Manager" in the bottom of the popup screen, you can hover your pointer over the "Extras" folder down in the bottom and the small yellow info will tell you where you will find the package that you need to import.

Once that is done, go down to the "library" section in the left pane with "Project" and within it the "Android" tab open. Open the java section of the library and open the APKExpansionPolicy class.
If you have errors and the import org.apache.http.NameValuePair and the import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils are pale grey, open the build.gradle(Project:whatever) and make sure that in "buildscript" under "dependancies" you have the "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0" included. The 1.5.0 might be different in your case. I guess it depends on your Studio version. Mine is 1.5.1. If yours is newer, you will be reminded to update the numbers.

After that, go to "build.gradle(Module:library) and include the "useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' into the "android"section. Sync Now (R/H top corner) should be offered. Do it.

If you get further error messages (I wouldn't know it because I did it the other way round), the Apache files might be missing from your project, as apache is not supported anymore. Find them in C/D:Users/Yourname/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23/optional and copy/paste them into yourproject/app/libs folder. You should have an optional.json and an org.apache.http.legacy.jar file in there. You might be better off going to apache's website and dowloading the newest version: http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi Unzip it anywhere you want, open it, go to "lib", copy the httpclient-4.5.1.jar file and replace the org.apache.http.legacy.jar file with it.

Sync and rebuild/clean your project and it should be good to go.

Just in case, open your terminal (L/H bottom of Android Studio) and type in "gradlew clean". It will install a few things. Once it is done, type in "gradlew assemble". It will take a few minutes to finish, but it will give you the errors if you have any of course.
If you cannot type in anything in the Terminal, launch command prompt (Windows button+R), type in cmd, hit OK, right click on the title of the small black popup screen (C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe), Properties, Options, in the bottom of the window check that "Use legacy console" is thicked. Restart A.Studio.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The version of the Apache HTTP client provided on stock Android was [very very old](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/android-port.html).

> Google Android 1.0 was released with a pre-BETA snapshot of Apache HttpClient. To coincide with the first Android release Apache HttpClient 4.0 APIs had to be frozen prematurely, while many of interfaces and internal structures were still not fully worked out. As Apache HttpClient 4.0 was maturing the project was expecting Google to incorporate the latest code improvements into their code tree. Unfortunately it did not happen.

While you *could* keep using the old deprecated library via the `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` workaround (suggested by @Jinu and others), you really need to bite the bullet and update to something else, for example the native Android [`HttpUrlConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), or if that doesn't meet your needs, you can use the [OkHttp library](http://square.github.io/okhttp/), which is what `HttpUrlConnection` is [internally based upon](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/29p3zz/til_okhttp_engine_is_backing_httpurlconnection_as/) anyway.

OkHttp actually has a [compatibility layer](http://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp-apache/) that uses the same API as the Apache client, though they don't implement *all* of the same features, so your mileage may vary.

While [it is possible to import a newer version of the Apache client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32805048/2125915) (as suggested by @MartinPfeffer), it's likely that most of the classes and methods you were using before have been deprecated, and there is a pretty big risk that updating will introduce bugs in your code (for example I found some connections that previously worked from behind a proxy no longer worked), so this isn't a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had to post as none of the above answers worked completely for me.

I am using Android Studio

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
```

Step 1: Download lastest jar file (http://www-eu.apache.org/dist//httpcomponents/httpclient/binary/httpcomponents-client-4.5.2-bin.zip)

Step 2: Copy paste the .jar file to the libs folder (create if does not exist already) in your module (can be app or library)

Step 3: Right click on the jar and "Add as Library". It will automatically add the jar file as a dependency in your module's gradle file

Step 4: Now automatically your problem will get resolved but in case you are using proguard in your app, it will give you warning about duplicate class files and won't let you build. It is a known bug and you need to add following to your proguard-rules

```
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.**
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I updated one of my libraries in my android project.

I'm using Reservoir as my cache storage solution: https://github.com/anupcowkur/Reservoir

I went from:

```
compile 'com.anupcowkur:reservoir:2.1'
```

To:

```
compile 'com.anupcowkur:reservoir:3.1.0'
```

The library author must have removed the commons-io library from the repo so my app no longer worked.

I had to manually include the commons-io by adding this onto gradle:

```
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.5

Answer (score 0):

I cloned the following: https://github.com/google/play-licensing

Then I imported that into my project.