# Error:(68, 45) error: cannot find symbol class BasicHttpParams .. etc

Tags: android

I have writeen code for login activity with php path server
and now I just copied the code and used it in new application.
This is my code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected EditText username;
    private EditText password;
    protected String enteredUsername;
    private final String serverUrl = "http://login/index.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username_field);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password_field);
        Button loginButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                enteredUsername = username.getText().toString();
                String enteredPassword = password.getText().toString();

                if(enteredUsername.equals("") || enteredPassword.equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username or password must be filled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                if(enteredUsername.length() <= 1 || enteredPassword.length() <= 1){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username or password length must be greater than one", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                // request authentication with remote server4
                AsyncDataClass asyncRequestObject = new AsyncDataClass();
                asyncRequestObject.execute(serverUrl, enteredUsername, enteredPassword);
            }
        });

        ;
    }

    private class AsyncDataClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);

            String jsonResult = "";
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", params[1]));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", params[2]));
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return jsonResult;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            System.out.println("Resulted Value: " + result);
            if(result.equals("") || result == null){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Server connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            int jsonResult = returnParsedJsonObject(result);
            if(jsonResult == 0){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            if(jsonResult == 1){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("USERNAME", enteredUsername);
                intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", "You have been successfully login");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
        private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            String rLine = "";
            StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            try {
                while ((rLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    answer.append(rLine);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return answer;
        }
    }
    private int returnParsedJsonObject(String result){

        JSONObject resultObject = null;
        int returnedResult = 0;
        try {
            resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
            returnedResult = resultObject.getInt("success");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return returnedResult;
    }
}
```

but there is red lines under the http request code :-

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);

            String jsonResult = "";
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", params[1]));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", params[2]));
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return jsonResult;
        }
```

there is red line under BasicHttpParams and under HttpClient and under HttpPost .....etc.
When I run the application these errors appear :-

> Error:(68, 45) error: cannot find symbol class BasicHttpParams
>   Error:(72, 13) error: cannot find symbol class HttpClient Error:(72,
>   41) error: cannot find symbol class DefaultHttpClient Error:(73, 37)
>   error: cannot find symbol class HttpPost Error:(77, 22) error: cannot
>   find symbol class NameValuePair Error:(80, 40) error: cannot find
>   symbol class UrlEncodedFormEntity Error:(77, 68) error: cannot find
>   symbol class NameValuePair Error:(79, 40) error: cannot find symbol
>   class BasicNameValuePair Error:(82, 17) error: cannot find symbol
>   class HttpResponse Error:(85, 22) error: cannot find symbol class
>   ClientProtocolException Error:(73, 13) error: cannot find symbol class
>   HttpPost Error:(78, 40) error: cannot find symbol class
>   BasicNameValuePair

what's the problem and how I can fix it ? help me and thanks.

Comment: This link may help you: [Apache HttpClient](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32323624/2335844)

Comment: works with me thanks