# warning deprecated in eclipse for basichttpparams,httpconnectionparams and httpparams

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i had problems when getting this warning..

```
//import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
'import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams' is deprecated   
'import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams' is deprecated  
'import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams' is deprecated
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP 
import org.json.JSONArray    
import org.json.JSONException    
import org.json.JSONObject     

//import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient   
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder    
//import java.io.IOException
```

function (timeout code based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1565243/208273) by [kuester2000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67350/kuester2000))

```
try { 
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    //HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
    HttpClient httpclient =HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
                    try{
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/hari.php");
                
                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity("envelope",HTTP.UTF_8);
                    httppost.setEntity(se); 
                    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                    // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
                    int timeoutConnection = 3000;
                    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
                    // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
                    // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
                    int timeoutSocket = 3000;
                    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket); 
                    
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent(); 
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
```

i am using android 5.1.1(API22)..what should i do when i got this warning error deprecated?anyone can help me?thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556605/org-apache-http-httpentity-is-deprecated-how-to-solve-this-error-in-android-s

Comment: don't use deprecated material. there's a reason it's deprecated

Comment: is there any suggestion to maintain the code without change it?means its there any backward compatibility??i had try use appcompat-v7 but nothing change..the deprecated still there.